# Finding begin and end of year/month/day/hour

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I'm using the following snipped to find the begin and end of several time periods in Joda. The little devil on my left shoulder says thats the way to go... but I dont believe him.

Could anybody with some joda experience take a brief look and tell me that the little guy is right?

(It will be only used for UTC datetime objects)

Thank you!

```
/* Year */
private static DateTime endOfYear(DateTime dateTime) {
    return endOfDay(dateTime).withMonthOfYear(12).withDayOfMonth(31);
}

private static DateTime beginningOfYear(DateTime dateTime) {
    return beginningOfMonth(dateTime).withMonthOfYear(1);
}

/* Month */
private static DateTime endOfMonth(DateTime dateTime) {
    return endOfDay(dateTime).withDayOfMonth(dateTime.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue());
}

private static DateTime beginningOfMonth(DateTime dateTime) {
    return beginningOfday(dateTime).withDayOfMonth(1);
}

/* Day */
private static DateTime endOfDay(DateTime dateTime) {
    return endOfHour(dateTime).withHourOfDay(23);
}

private static DateTime beginningOfday(DateTime dateTime) {
    return beginningOfHour(dateTime).withHourOfDay(0);
}

/* Hour */
private static DateTime beginningOfHour(DateTime dateTime) {
    return dateTime.withMillisOfSecond(0).withSecondOfMinute(0).withMinuteOfHour(0);
}

private static DateTime endOfHour(DateTime dateTime) {
    return dateTime.withMillisOfSecond(999).withSecondOfMinute(59).withMinuteOfHour(59);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing jUnit tests?

Comment: I'm looking for a simpler way than this, it looks a bit awkward to me. But it works, even for some corner cases.

Comment: I think you need to reverse the operations for endOfYear. It looks like 2/2/10 would give you a date of 12/28/10. From a XP/TDD perspective, do you need all of these beginning/end methods? If all you need is the begin and end of the year and month, then implement just that. If you later find you need day and hour you can add them. Most likely, you won't need them all. And less code means less places for bugs to hide.

Comment: shhhh.... you're right. month is a special case. (upvoting yours and boris comments)

Comment: It's fixed. I need all of these methods and I hoped joda would provide something useful.

Comment: It looks like there are no "readymade" APIs available for this from JODA and going by the look of your code, it seems like a fairly useful feature to be able to "ROUND off" a date to the near minute/hour/or  so. If I were you,I will submit this utility plus the tests to be included in the DateTimeUtil of joda or somesuch class (Of course it would be their decision to accept/reject/modify it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joda does supply DateMidnight and LocalDate that might alleviate having to deal with hours and minutes so much on the cases where you really only care about day boundaries.  LocalDate also implements the interface ReadablePartial, and it might be worthwhile to look at making other implementations of that which reflect the fields of interest.

Comment: The midnight-relate classes and methods were deprecated in Joda-Time. Replaced with [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay--) method.

Answer (score 0):

I know the java libraries are 0 based (ie January is 0, December is 11). I don't think Joda is, but if you're not sure double check that.

Comment: No, Joda-Time (and java.time) use sane ordinal numbers with 1-12 for January-December.